# Events wxpython, trigger wrong function

Tags: python, events, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

my code:

for i in range(0,3):

```
    self.thermopage.selectcompbutt.variables[0][0].Bind(event=wx.EVT_BUTTON,
       handler =lambda event,row=0,page=0:self.OnButtonClick(event,row,page),
        id = self.thermopage.selectcompbutt.variables[0][0].GetId())
```

def OnButtonClick(self,event,ro,whatpage):

```
    self.dialogframe= wx.Frame(self, size=(100,140))
    self.dialogpanel=wx.Panel(self.dialogframe)
    self.dialogsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.text = wx.StaticText(self.dialogpanel,id=wx.NewId() ,
                          label = "Available COM-Ports")
    self.dropdown = wx.ComboBox(self.dialogpanel, id=wx.NewId(), choices= strings,
                                     size=(100,10))
    self.chosebutton = wx.Button(self.dialogpanel,id = wx.NewId(), label = "Select", 
                                   size= (100,15))
    self.dialogsizer.Add(self.chosebutton,1, wx.LEFT)
    self.dialogpanel.SetSizerAndFit(self.dialogsizer)
    self.dialogframe.Show()
    print self.chosebutton.GetId()
    self.chosebutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler=self.OnSelect(event))
```

def OnSelect(self, evt):

```
      #do something
```

The problem is that when I push the button that shall open the dialogframe(where the chosebutton is), the OnSelect() function runs.

I would like to open dialogframe, and when i press the "chosebutton", OnSelect() runs.

How can I do this, and why does the function trigger?

Comment: When you are binding to OnSelect you have () which has called the method and then bound to the result of Onselect, when you bind to a method or function you should not use () so the bind is to the object itself.

Comment: Great! thank you, that fixed it. such an easy solution :-)

Comment: Added my comment as an answer as it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you are binding to OnSelect you have () which has called the method and then bound to the result of Onselect, when you bind to a method or function you should not use () so the bind is to the object itself.